# A couple of new feature ideas to SO Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs, discussion

Since SO Careers is supposed to be a new job search site that works better for IT people than anything else out there, I just came up with an idea for a new feature that I would find very helpful that nobody else has.  (It might have been suggested before, I don't claim that it's a *unique* idea.  Just that no site is doing it, that I know of.)

I have variations of my CV posted on several job sites, and as some people recommend, I customize it on an almost constant basis.  (My SO CV isn't customized as often, since the employers seem free to use language like "ninja" and "rockstar", I wrote my CV to reflect who I am and what I've accomplished and what I want to accomplish in the future, rather than just the uber-formal language used in most resumes.)  And I've been job searching for a whole year now, only had 6 phone interviews and only two face to face interviews.

It sure would be nice if I could get some sort of feedback on my CV from the employers.  It would of course have to be anonymized.  But it would be nice to know if my language is too flippant, too vague, or simply missing some skill.  It could even be aggregated and still be valuable.  Having one CV that represents me isn't working, and having resumes customized for every job application isn't working either.  Some honest feedback would be wonderful.

We could do the same for the job postings.  I would comment on job postings that ask for ninjas and rock stars, for example.  (Do you really want egotistical people on your team?)  I'm also intimidated by those kinds of postings so I don't apply for them, as well as the ones that ask for "expert level knowledge of ..."  I've worked with OpenVMS for over 20 years and I don't consider myself an expert even in that.  There is *always* more to learn!

Comment: Can you post your CW link as a comment, out of curiosity? Anyways, having a lot of ego helps in job hunting. Convincing yourself that you not just an "expert" but really the best will greatly help your chances of getting the job (of course, it won't help to DO your job, but hey it's a first step)

Comment: Yeah, that sort of terminology irritates me a bit -- I've worked with people who thought they were rock stars (in multiple senses of the word), and they can be a bit challenging to deal with. Either they think they are so awesome that they don't have to listen to anyone, or they think that work is a non-stop party and it's impossible to have any sort of serious discussion... or both!

Comment: Kop, I have confidence in my skills and abilities.  I just don't feel that it's appropriate to claim to be expert/rockstar/ninja.  It's possible that I don't have hollywood-level charisma, but just as soon as I claim to be an expert in something, the interviewer will test me and find details that I didn't know, thus making me out to be a liar.  I think only people with the charisma to not be called on their claims can really succeed with this approach.